# How to run NUnit from a deployed Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a set of unit tests that need to be run by people outside of my office who don't have access to visual studio. I have a project that contains Nunit tests and I want to deploy a windows forms application where you click a button and the project with the unit tests will execute the NUnit GUI Runner. I can run the unit tests using the NUnit GUI from within Visual Studio but is it possible to run the NUnit tests using the NUnit GUI from a deployed WinForms application?

I'm not looking to use NUnit inside the WinForms application, just launch the NUnit-Gui and run the tests. Basically a button on the WinForms application that will launch the NUnit-Gui.

Comment: Are you asking about running [NUnit-Gui](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.2.10) from a WinForms application? Or would NUnit-Gui as a standalone test runner do what you want?

Comment: @hunch_hunch I want to launch the NUnit-Gui from a WinForms application to run the unit tests which are a separate project inside the WinForms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial example of how to start [NUnit-Gui](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.2.10) (targeting a specific assembly containing NUnit tests) from a C# WinForms application when a button is clicked. This assumes the machine on which the user is running the application has NUnit installed in a certain path. You could of course deploy NUnit with your WinForms application and/or configure the location from where it is run. With this code, the user will still have to click the `Run` button in the NUnit window that pops up to actually run the tests.

```
namespace NUnitGuiRunner
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System.Diagnostics;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RunTestsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit.exe", @"C:\PathToTests\SomeUnitTests.dll");
        }
    }
}
```